# Not able to create Jfrog artifactory with record in Java

Tags: java, artifactory, record, java-17

I am trying to create jfrog artifactory by using record in JAVA but I am getting this error

error: class, interface, or enum expected
public record abcDTO(String transactionId, String transStatus, String transMessage) {}

Every time I am trying to create the artifactory this error shows up

Comment: The requirement does not seem to clear. What do you mean by creating Artifactory ? Artifactory is an application which is used to store your binaries(artifacts). Are you trying to start Artifactory? or you are trying to deploy artifacts to Artifactory server and facing some issue? Please elaborate on your requirement and the process that you are following.

Comment: Hi I am trying to create a jar using jfrog and deploy that jar on  jfrog server and use it on my application

Comment: So, jfrog is a deployment tool for the compiled binaries, yet your problem is an error when compiling the source code? Are you sure that your problem is even related to jfrog? It sounds like you are just using an outdated compiler (or a language setting to an old Java version).